# How to import datacommons.utils as utils

Tags: python, jupyter

I am using [Anadonda Navigator](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-navigator) (default base root) and [Jupyter Notebooks](https://jupyter.org/) to make python scripts.

I want to use the [datacommons_pandas](https://docs.datacommons.org/api/pandas/) module.

I am able to install but not import `datacommons_pandas`.
(Module not found error)

In Anaconda I see the pip and conda modules are installed (see image).
The key difference is the icons conda vs pip

[image: Conda vs Pip packages in Anacoda Navigator]

Also, `pip list` shows the modules are definitely installed.

Module `datacommon_pandas` is not importing due to `import datacommons.utils as utils` failing.

Can I check that `datacommons.utils` is there somehow?

Example of issue:
[image]

Example with both modules:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a code snippet along with the error log. Also base env in Anaconda comes with a pip module so you dont have to install it separately. If you cant import a library, check if you have that particular library installed or not

Comment: Added image with code and error

Comment: Have you tried updating this module? Run in conda prompt: conda install -c conda-forge datacommons. Then if not solved run in windows command prompt: pip install --upgrade datacommons-pandas

Comment: @KrzysztofChojnacki I had to install using pip, hence the different icons. The package wasn't available via conda to install. I did a fresh install only yesterday so I assume it is ok. I can reinstall to be sure.